# If user is logged-in display/hide widgets ( siteorigine)

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I want to hide widgets from home page when user logged in 
I need help..

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest, though not always optimal, is to use CSS. In the vast majority of WordPress themes (ones assigning body classes), `logged-in` and `home` will be applied to the body tag automatically, when appropriate, and every widget gets a unique ID wherever it's displayed.

So, if I wanted to hide a given widget to logged in users, on the home page only, I'd use Chrome Inspector or other inspection tool to find the widget, find the ID assigned to its div tag, open the Customizer, open Additional CSS, and add the following code - say if the widget's ID turned out to be `text-24`:

```
/*CONCEAL text-24 WIDGET FROM LOGGED IN USERS ON HOME PAGE */
.home.logged-in #text-24 {
    display: none;
}
```

(If I wanted it to remain visible to admin users - like myself - I'd need to do a little more work, for instance by adding a user class to body classes, or by using the `admin-bar` class if I happened to be hiding the Admin Bar already from users below Administrator level.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use third-party WordPress plugin "**AH Display Widgets**" to show/hide widgets for specific **page/post/archive/single/taxonomy** page for **logged-in/unlogged users**.

AH Display Widgets: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ah-display-widgets/

You simply need to select from drop-down whether to show specific widget to logged-in users or unlogged users.

Hope this helps...!!

[image]

Comment: link only answers are not actual answers over here

Comment: Thanks...Mark for pointing it out...I will remember this before posting an answer.